# Getting NameError: name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean 'id'?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

```
import bpy

class ColorPalettePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Color Palette"
    bl_idname = "COLOR_PALETTE_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column()

        colors = [
            (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),    # Black
            (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),    # White
            (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),    # Red
            (0.0, 1.0, 0.0),    # Green
            (0.0, 0.0, 1.0),    # Blue
            (1.0, 1.0, 0.0),    # Yellow
            (1.0, 0.0, 1.0),    # Magenta
            (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),    # Cyan
            (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),    # Gray
            (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),    # Maroon
            (0.0, 0.5, 0.0),    # Olive
            (0.0, 0.0, 0.5),    # Navy
            (0.5, 0.5, 0.0),    # Olive Green
            (0.5, 0.0, 0.5),    # Purple
            (0.0, 0.5, 0.5),    # Teal
            (0.8, 0.8, 0.8),    # Light Gray
            (0.8, 0.0, 0.0),    # Dark Red
            (0.0, 0.8, 0.0),    # Dark Green
            (0.0, 0.0, 0.8),    # Dark Blue
            (0.8, 0.8, 0.0),    # Dark Yellow
        ]

        for i in range(len(colors)):
            col = row.column()
            col.prop(context.scene, "color_%d" % i, text="", icon="COLOR")
            col.prop(context.scene, "color_%d" % i, text="", icon_value=layout.icon(colors[i]))

classes = [
    ColorPalettePanel
]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        bpy.types.Scene.__annotations__["color_%d" % i] = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
            name="Color %d" % i,
            subtype='COLOR',
            default=colors[i],
            min=0.0,
            max=1.0
        )

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.__annotations__["color_%d" % i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Getting the below error**

`line 51, in register:  NameError: name 'i' is not defined. Did you mean 'id'?`

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestion or help. Thx

Comment: If you look closely at line 51: `bpy.types.Scene.__annotations__["color_%d" % i]` then you will notice that there is the loop variable `i` used but there is no `for i` loop. This and the following statements are executed in the `for cls` loop which doesn't seem right. The same problem is in the `unregister()` function.

Answer (score 1):

As @[Blunder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/107598/blunder) has pointed out, your `i` variable is not defined. You probably wanted to have a second loop, `for i in range(len(colors)):` and also your `colors` variable needs to be defined globally. Here is the fixed script.

```
import bpy

colors = [
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),    # Black
    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),    # White
    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),    # Red
    (0.0, 1.0, 0.0),    # Green
    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0),    # Blue
    (1.0, 1.0, 0.0),    # Yellow
    (1.0, 0.0, 1.0),    # Magenta
    (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),    # Cyan
    (0.5, 0.5, 0.5),    # Gray
    (0.5, 0.0, 0.0),    # Maroon
    (0.0, 0.5, 0.0),    # Olive
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.5),    # Navy
    (0.5, 0.5, 0.0),    # Olive Green
    (0.5, 0.0, 0.5),    # Purple
    (0.0, 0.5, 0.5),    # Teal
    (0.8, 0.8, 0.8),    # Light Gray
    (0.8, 0.0, 0.0),    # Dark Red
    (0.0, 0.8, 0.0),    # Dark Green
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.8),    # Dark Blue
    (0.8, 0.8, 0.0),    # Dark Yellow
]

class ColorPalettePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Color Palette"
    bl_idname = "COLOR_PALETTE_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column()

        for i in range(len(colors)):
            col = row.column()
            col.prop(context.scene, "color_%d" % i, text="", icon="COLOR")
            col.prop(context.scene, "color_%d" % i, text="", icon_value=layout.icon(colors[i]))

classes = [
    ColorPalettePanel
]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        bpy.types.Scene.__annotations__["color_%d" % i] = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
            name="Color %d" % i,
            subtype='COLOR',
            default=colors[i],
            min=0.0,
            max=1.0
        )

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    for i in range(len(colors)):
        del bpy.types.Scene.__annotations__["color_%d" % i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Are you sure there should be only one *for* loop? Because so it loops over the single class "ColorPalettePanel" to register it and therefore it creates only one single color property in this loop. My guess is, there should be 2 loops. One to manage the classes and one for the color properties. The 2nd loop probably should iterate over all colors. The question lacks a bit of detail here.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It's missing clarity and it looks like the OP doesn't know what they want or what the code does since the error was very basic and should have been very understandable.

Comment: Ah I updated the code. You're right it probably needs this second loop for the colors I think `for i in range(len(colors)):`